# How do use Cast Queueing APIs when I don't have all Video urls available at once?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

In my android app I am using `CastCompanionLibrary` to cast videos to a cast device. I want to auto cast `Videos` in a queue format. There are Cast queuing `APIs` available to achieve this. 
But my problem is that I need to make a separate `API` call to fetch the `url` of each of the videos. 
Can I performing queuing using the Cast queuing `APIs` in such a situation?

Comment: yes, you can do. pls ref this https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android.

Comment: Could you please provide code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

Queuing APIs have methods to insert an item into an existing queue so you can start a queue from one element and then as you have more items available, you can call `VideoCastManager.queueInsertItems()` to add the new ones.